# slow read query causes other c3p0 threads to block on acquireStatement

Tags: java, mysql, performance, c3p0

I have a table `articles` with 500k rows. I only use `select` queries on it via a web app. All of my pages load fast (~20ms) and each consists of one or two fast queries (~10ms each). Those fast queries may either select something from the `articles` table or do something irrelevant, like selecting a row from another small table (5 rows).

I am having 30 pageviews per second on this webapp with no problem.

Sometimes though a specific page executes a select query which is very slow (~30 seconds) because it almost does a full table scan on the 500k rows of the `articles` table and just returns 3 rows. When this happens the other fast pages start slowing down heavily and at some point they completelly block.

Note that all pages use transactions and all the queries are `select`s so they shouldn't affect each other to much, performance wise.

I also validate the above by executing this slow query manually from a console (outside of the scope of the webapp) and the fast pages from the webapp are not affected at all. So I think that something weird is going on in the application layer.

Any idea why does this happen? Why are all threads waiting at `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache.acquireStatement`?

Some data:

- MySQL: 5.5.32
- engine: InnoDB
- jdbc driver: mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
- pool: c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar
- orm: hibernate 3.6.8
- pool config: http://pastebin.com/3zMARM1B
- thread dump while stuck: http://pastebin.com/YGisWCzY
- tomcat: tomcat-6.0.32
- jdk: 1.6.xx

Comment: You might try to use a different engine, such as MyIsam.  I don't know if that will help or not...

Comment: Could it be that the prepared statement that is still running is about to be evicted from statement cached? (which causes other threads to wait until it can be done) See: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2390809. Try increasing statement cache size and see if it helps

Comment: You raise a valid point @SamiKorhonen. Thanks. Will try it out and let you know.

Comment: That was it!!! I changed it from `50` to `5000` and the problem is gone! I will benchmark my app to see whether `0` (no statement caching) is good enough. The `50` was there since 2008 because I've seen it in 2 hibernate books but never really researched on what exactly it does and what possible sideeffects it could have. Please post it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that the slow running prepared statement is about to be evicted from statement cache. This would cause other threads to wait until statement can be closed. Increasing statement cache size should fix the issue.